# Problem with checking that all EditTexts are empty

Tags: java, android, if-statement, android-edittext

I have 5 EditTexts, when I am clicking on the button, I want to check that all of them are not empty in order to take data from them and put it into the database, and start another activity. If all of them are empty, a message would be displayed that "You need to fill everything". However, when all EditTexts are empty and I press the button, application crashes. How can I solve this problem and what can I do to get the desired result? (The code is not ended yet.)

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

DatabaseHelper myDB;
Button btnAdd;
EditText editText1,editText2,editText3,editText4,editText5;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
    editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.year);
    editText3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.month);
    editText4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.day);
    editText5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.price);



    btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_add);
    myDB = new DatabaseHelper(this);




    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String name1 = editText1.getText().toString();
            String year2 = editText2.getText().toString();
            int year1 = Integer.parseInt(year2);
            String month2 = editText3.getText().toString();
            int month1 = Integer.parseInt(month2);
            String day2 = editText4.getText().toString();
            int day1 = Integer.parseInt(day2);
            String price2 = editText5.getText().toString();
            int price1 = Integer.parseInt(price2);


            if (name1.length() != 0 && year2.length() != 0 && month2.length() != 0 && day2.length() != 0 && price2.length() != 0) {

                AddData(name1, year1, month1, day1, price1);

                editText1.setText("");
                editText2.setText("");
                editText3.setText("");
                editText4.setText("");
                editText5.setText("");

                Intent intent = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            } else {

                Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this, "You need to fill everything", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }


        }
    });
}




public void AddData(String name1, int year1, int month1, int day1, int price1) {

    boolean insertData = myDB.addData(name1,year1,month1,day1,price1);

    if(insertData==true){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Data Successfully Inserted!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong :(.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add your crash report from logcat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crash happens here:

```
int year1 = Integer.parseInt(year2);
```

When `EditText` is empty, you are passing an empty string to `Integer.parseInt`, which results in `NumberFormatException`. To avoid this, move the parsing code into the validation block.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    String name1 = editText1.getText().toString();
    String year2 = editText2.getText().toString();
    String month2 = editText3.getText().toString();
    String day2 = editText4.getText().toString();
    String price2 = editText5.getText().toString();

    if (name1.length() != 0 && year2.length() != 0 && month2.length() != 0 && day2.length() != 0 && price2.length() != 0) {

        // Move parsing code here
        int year1 = Integer.parseInt(year2);
        int month1 = Integer.parseInt(month2);
        int day1 = Integer.parseInt(day2);
        int price1 = Integer.parseInt(price2);
        AddData(name1, year1, month1, day1, price1);

        editText1.setText("");
        editText2.setText("");
        editText3.setText("");
        editText4.setText("");
        editText5.setText("");

        Intent intent = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    } else {

        Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this, "You need to fill everything", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can allow the user to press the button only after entering text to all of your editTexts like this:

```
if (all editTexts got text inside) {
  //not all editTexts got text inside them, user cant press the button
  button.setClickable(false);  
}
else{
  //all editTexts got text inside them, user can now press the button
  button.setClickable(true);  
}
```

**Note** - "all editTexts got text inside" that I wrote inside the if statment is for you to make in any way that you would like to check.